# Find a special part in a string

Tags: c++, string

I try to locate a special part in a string.
The example of string as follow:
`22.21594087,1.688530832,0`

I want to locate `1.688530832` out.
I tried

`temp.substr(temp.find(",")+1,temp.rfind(","));`

and got `1.688530832,0`.
I replaced rfind() with find_last_of() but still got the same result.

`temp.substr(temp.find(",")+1,temp.find_last_of(","));`

I know this is a simple problem and there are other solutions.But I just want to know why the rfind did not work. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument for `substr` is not the ending index, but rather the length of the substring you want. Simply throw in the length of `1.688530832` and you'll be fine.

If the length of the search string is not available, then you can find the position of the last comma and subtract that from the position of the first character of the special word:

```
auto beginning_index = temp.find(",") + 1;
auto last_comma_index = temp.rfind(",");
temp.substr(beginning_index, last_comma_index - beginning_index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are doing. You are trying to have kind of iterators to the beginning and the end of a substring. Unfortunately, `substr` does not work that way, and instead expects an index and *an offset* from that index to select the substring.

What you were trying to achieve can be done with `std::find`, which does work with iterators:

```
auto a = std::next(std::find(begin(temp), end(temp), ','));
auto b = std::next(std::find(rbegin(temp), rend(temp), ',')).base();
std::cout << std::string(a, b);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33f1a69506f43438)